# Нужна ли запятая на стыке с тире?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, синтаксис, тире

*Этой строки — именно в таком виде, как её цитирует Бунин(,) — я у Бальмонта не нашёл.*

Фраза моя, поправить могу беспроблемно, но интересует именно пунктуация в представленном виде. У меня это «поглощение» запятой на стыке с тире уже превратилось в страшный сон. На мой вкус, она здесь лишняя, так как парное тире поглощает «внутреннее» обособление. Но вот как быть, когда там внутри парного тире законченное предложение?!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Этой строки — именно в таком виде, как её цитирует Бунин, — я у Бальмонта не нашел.**

[Розенталь](http://old-rozental.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=319):

> 4) как перед первым, так и перед вторым тире ставится запятая по условиям текста:
>   *Я забрался в угол, в кожаное кресло, такое большое, что в нём можно
>   было лежать, — дедушка всегда хвастался, называя его креслом князя
>   Грузинского, — забрался и смотрел, как скучно веселятся большие* (М.
>   Г.) — запятая перед первым тире закрывает предшествующую придаточную
>   часть, а **запятая перед вторым тире закрывает деепричастный оборот в
>   самой вставной конструкции**;

Я думаю, что это именно ваш случай, только у вас запятая закрывает придаточное предложение.

Comment: По-моему, данный подход применим к предложению из вопроса.   Кстати, в примере Розенталя тоже есть запятая, закрывающая   придаточную часть, только она стоит перед первым тире.  А кроме того, запятая, закрывающая деепричастный оборот, не отличается (в смысле подхода) от запятой, закрывающей придаточную часть.

Comment: Согласен, пример в тему. И все-таки здесь какие-то недоговорки есть... Я чуть позже найду ссылки.